# ¿Cómo reiniciar (borrar datos) de un archivo CSV?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un archivo CSV que acumula datos cada vez que ejecuta el programa:

```
0   2021-12-06  16:48:52.424938  Usuario 1   0   1
1   2021-12-06  16:52:47.856487  Usuario 2   2   2
2   2021-12-06  16:52:47.856487  Usuario 3   3   3
3   2021-12-06  17:59:06.617908  Usuario 4   2   4
4   2021-12-06  17:59:06.617908  Usuario 5   4   5
```

Pero estoy buscando la forma de eliminar todos los datos del CSV ejecutando un botón.

Ya probé con 'drop' de pandas pero no me estaría funcionando.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('partidas.csv')

filas = len(df.index)

df.drop(df.index[range(0, filas - 1)], inplace=True)
```

PD: Solo estoy buscando un método para eliminar todo los datos del archivo, el asunto del botón ya lo tengo hecho.

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo, extrae los datos del csv y los carga a un dataframe sin modificar el csv. Si lo que quieres es vaciar de contenido el csv, lo más fácil es reescribirlo asignándole un dataframe vacio.

Comment: puedes usar esto: df = pd.DataFrame()
df.to_csv("tu_archivo.csv", index=False)

Comment: Para vaciar tu archivo podrás hacerlo con `file = open("archivoDatos.csv", "w")`

Comment: El `drop` funciona pero solo en el dataframe, si no lo guardas tendrás lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Para **vaciar** o **eliminar** tus archivos podes utilizar algunas de estas opciones.

###### Archivo ejemplo nombrado: `archivoDatos.csv`

Borrar datos:

##### El **borrado** de datos en archivo:

```
def csv_borrar_datos():
    file = open("archivoDatos.csv", "w")
    file.close()
```

Sobrescribimos el archivo (W) pero sin datos para luego cerrarlo (close()).
El archivo queda vacío y cerrado. En este caso no es eliminado.

##### Eliminación definitivamente de archivo:

```
import os
def borrar_archivo():
    try:
        os.remove("archivoDatos.csv")
    except OSError:
        print("No se pudo borrar el archivo")
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: No hace falta especificar el cerrado del fichero con `with`

Comment: También se podía truncar el archivo haciendo `f=open("archivo.csv");f.truncate(0);f.close()`